# Datepicker - close when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Datepicker doesn't close when clicking outside

and if I select 10/09 and current date is 10/ 11 and refresh browser,

then it shows current date 10/11 on     `<input>`     tag,

but the selected date on datepicker keep showing 10/09

How do I fix this?

My code is below:

```
<div class="form-inline" align="right">
  <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="form-control" value='<%=selectDate%>' onchange="hide()">

  <script>
    $input = $("#datepicker");
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    $input.data('datepicker').hide = function() {};

  </script>
</div>
```

When I refresh the browser,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does changing `type="text"` to `type="date"` work? Like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j14rqmLt/)